# jooq select from a particular partition of the table

Tags: java, jooq

What is the right way to execute a select query on a particular partition of a table. For exmample I have a employees table that is range partitioned on a particular column.

Currently I do:

```
Result<Record> fetch = DSL.using(configuration())
  .select()
  .from(EMPLOYEES)
  .fetch();
```

what is the right way to execute the below sql (where p2 is a partition)

```
SELECT * FROM employees PARTITION (p2);
```

**UPDATE 1**
What about for update/insert when I am using Updatable record, example:

```
employeeRecord.attach(configuration())
employeeRecord.update(); // or insert
```

I assume I can do something like this but would that then handle optimistic lock case (which I am using via the version column on my table)

```
DSL.using(configuration())
                    .update("{0} partition (p2)", EMPLOYEES)
                    .set(EMPLOYEES.NAME, "abc")
                    .where(EMPLOYEES.ID.eq(123))
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't support `PARTITION` clauses on tables. The relevant feature request is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2774

You can easily work around this limitation by using the plain SQL templating API:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

```java
Result<Record> fetch = DSL.using(configuration())
  .select()
  .from("{0} partition (p2)", EMPLOYEES)
  .fetch();
```

The above is convenience for:

```java
Result<Record> fetch = DSL.using(configuration())
  .select()
  .from(DSL.table("{0} partition (p2)", EMPLOYEES))
  .fetch();
```

Comment: thanks this works, updated the question for updatableRecords case

Comment: @anuj: Would you mind removing the updates again and asking new questions? I'm not sure if the things are strictly related. Stack Overflow won't run out of question IDs soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going with examples from here, like

```
create.select(t.BOOKED_AT, t.AMOUNT,
         sum(t.AMOUNT).over().partitionByOne()
                      .orderBy(t.BOOKED_AT)
```

https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/window-functions/

Comment: The OP is asking about querying partitioned tables, which is something entirely else (although using the same keyword) than window functions.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'm not sure if jooq should have a native support for this, as it's totally Oracle dependent. Thanks for the correct answer!

Comment: I haven't checked other databases, but at least DB2 and PostgreSQL also support partitioned tables. I don't see a problem supporting this vendor-specific feature, although, it might not be a priority.